# Power BI Retrieve Last Column Value by Group

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working in a dashboard that control some kpis at my company. Now, I need to compare every result with the previous one, according to employee number. In the sample below, I show a little exemple of my data, and the expected result in the last column (previous score). I've tryed to solve that using a lot os calculated columns. I got close using the following:

```
PreviousScore = 
VAR EMPNUMBER = BASE[Employee Number]
VAR REF = BASE[Score]

RETURN
CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(BASE[Employee Number];EMPNUMBER);FILTER(BASE;BASE[Employee Number]=EMPNUMBER);FILTER(BASE;BASE[Date]<EARLIER(BASE[Date])))
```

Employee Number Date    Score   Previous score

1234    01/01/2019  1   BLANK

1235    01/01/2019  4   BLANK

1236    01/01/2019  2   BLANK

1288    01/01/2019  0   BLANK

1259    01/01/2019  0   BLANK

1234    01/02/2019  3   1

1235    01/02/2019  4   4

1236    01/02/2019  1   2

1288    01/02/2019  2   0

1259    01/02/2019  4   0

1234    01/03/2019  1   3

1235    01/03/2019  2   4

1236    01/03/2019  3   1

1288    01/03/2019  0   2

1259    01/03/2019  1   4

1234    01/04/2019  2   1

1235    01/04/2019  3   2

1236    01/04/2019  8   3

1288    01/04/2019  BLANK   0

1259    01/04/2019  BLANK   1

I hope someone could help with this issue.

LW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no dependance between your dates, you pickup the earlier column and by accident they are in the right order.

The following query will give you the right result:

```
Previous score = 
    var empNR = score[Employee Number]
    var theDate = score[Date]
    var empData = FILTER(score;score[Employee Number] = empNR)
    var prevDate = CALCULATE(MAX(score[Date]);empData;score[Date] < theDate)
    return CALCULATE(MAX(score[Score]);FILTER(empData; score[Date] = prevDate))
```

1. I filter on emp number to get the data of that employee
2. I get the prevDate by getting the max of all dates which are lower
   than selected date
3. last step is to get the one row and return the score